# Does [=] imply that all local variables will be copied?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, capture

When I write a lambda with `[=]`, does it mean that all my local variables will be copied into members of the created struct or can I assume that only those will that are actually used in the lambda? For example:

```
void f()
{
    vector<int> v(10000);
    const int n = 5;
    const int DivByNCnt = count_if(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>(), 
          [=](int i)
          {
             return i % n == 0;
          });
}
```

Which of the following, if any, is true?

- both n and v will be copied
- n will be copied, v will not
- n will be copied, v may or may not be copied depending on the implmenentation/optimization settings.

Suppose for the argument's sake that vector's copy constructor has side effects.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the semantics of c++11, anything except only `n` being captured would be completely crazy with respect to the semantics of every other language with first-class anonymous functions and proper closures.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

No. It just means that all local variables from the ambient scope are available for lookup inside the body of the lambda. Only *if* you refer to a name of an ambient local variable will that variable be captured, and it'll be captured by value.

The "capture anything" shorthands `=` and `&` are just syntactic sugar, essentially, telling the compiler to "figure out what I mean".

---

A formal reference from 5.1.2/11-12:

> If a lambda-expression has an associated *capture-default* and its *compound-statement* odr-uses [...] a variable with automatic storage duration and the odr-used entity is not explicitly captured, then the odr-used entity is said to be *implicitly captured* [...]
>
> An entity is *captured* if it is captured explicitly or implicitly.

Note that "*capture-default*" refers to `[=]` and `[&]`. To repeat, specifying a capture-default doesn't capture anything; only odr-using a variable does.

Comment: I am in no doubt that you are correct, but have you got any references?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: See 5.1.2/11-12, about "implicit and explicit capturing". It's *using the variables inside the lambda body* that does the capturing.

Answer (score 22):

No! (thankfully)

You can instrument your code to check whether your compiler actually does it (or not). For example [gcc 4.8.0](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3HTwkb$3) appears to be compliant.

---

As to what the Standard actually mandates (working backward):

> §5.1.2/14 An entity is *captured by copy* if it is implicitly captured and the capture-default is `=` or if it is explicitly captured with a capture that does not include an `&`. For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed nonstatic data member is declared in the closure type.
>
> $5.1.2/11 If a lambda-expression has an associated capture-default and its compound-statement odr-uses (3.2) `this` or a variable with automatic storage duration and the odr-used entity is not explicitly captured, *then the odr-used entity is said to be implicitly captured*; such entities shall be declared within the reaching scope of the lambda expression.
>
> §5.1.2/9 A lambda-expression whose smallest enclosing scope is a block scope (3.3.3) is a local lambda expression; any other lambda-expression shall not have a capture-list in its lambda-introducer. The **reaching scope** of a local lambda expression is the set of enclosing scopes up to and including the innermost enclosing function and its parameters. [ Note: This reaching scope includes any intervening lambda-expressions. —end note ]

Comment: MSVC 10.0 does not copy v, but I wanted to know if there's a  guaranteed that v will not be copied!

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: I added the corresponding quotes of the Standard. Only the captured members are supposed to be "hosted" in the closure type according to §5.1.2/14.