# C++ initialize priority_queue with custom compare function

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I have a `Dijkstra` class which uses a `priority_queue` with a custom compare function. I named the queue `DijkstraPriorityQueue` with a `using` statement. Inside the class constructor, I initialize the queue. To do that, I give the compare function in a lambda expression.

For the first queue, `PQ1`, the compare function is `{ return distTo[u] > distTo[v]; }` and this compiles fine, because the `vector<float> distTo` is a member of the class.

But for the second queue, `PQ2`, the function is `{ return distTo2[u] > distTo2[v]; }` where `vector<float> distTo2` is just a temporary variable inside the constructor, and that doesn't compile. (I think that's the reason at least)

Also, I randomly tried to change `vector<float> distTo2` to `static vector<float> distTo2` by intuition and it compiles, however I don't think this is what I want to be doing. I am not familiar with static variables inside functions, since that doesn't exist in Java or C#. At any case, what is a clean solution to make the code below compile and work as intended ?

**Dijkstra.h**

```
class Dijkstra
{
public:
    Dijkstra();  
    ~Dijkstra();       

private:    
    vector<float> distTo;
};
```

**Dijkstra.cpp**

```
using DijkstraPriorityQueue = priority_queue<int, vector<int>, function<bool(int, int)>>;

Dijkstra::Dijkstra()
{           
    distTo = vector<float>(V, FLT_MAX);
    // Compiles fine
    DijkstraPriorityQueue PQ1 = DijkstraPriorityQueue([this](int u, int v)
        { return distTo[u] > distTo[v]; });

    vector<float> distTo2 = vector<float>(V, FLT_MAX);
    // Doesn't compile
    DijkstraPriorityQueue PQ2 = DijkstraPriorityQueue([this](int u, int v)
        { return distTo2[u] > distTo2[v]; });
}
```

**Edit:**

The following code compiles too. Any clues why ? Can someone explain what **capture** is on lambda expressions ? Or how should I write my code properly in this specific case ?

```
DijkstraPriorityQueue PQ2 = DijkstraPriorityQueue([distTo2](int u, int v)
    { return distTo2[u] > distTo2[v]; });
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918231/using-out-of-scope-variables-in-c11-lambda-expressions)?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi It compiles with both `[=]` and `[&]`. Any clues what should I be using here ?

Comment: You should use `[&]` as it it'll prevent unnecessary copy of the vector.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi `[=]` would copy the whole vector ? holy mother of god.

Comment: Yes, it'll [`pass-by-value`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) meaning it would copy.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Out of curiosity, when does the copy occur exactly ?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612513/does-imply-that-all-local-variables-will-be-copied?).

Comment: For anyone wondering about the previous question I asked in the comments: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181464/do-c11-lambdas-capture-variables-they-dont-use) is a great source of information.

Comment: I would use `vector<double>`, not `vector<float>`. As the default choice. E.g. floating point literals default to `double`. Is there any particular reason that you desire less precision and smaller range?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Do you think that's better ? I am simply using float because that's the standard for C# and Java. I am not that experienced with C++.

Comment: @Shiro: There may well be limited contexts (graphics programming?) where single-precision float is "standard" for C# and Java, but `double` is the default. E.g. the type of the literal `3.14` is `double` in Java, C# and C++. And C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main aspects of your question:

- What is this “capture” thing, and why the error?
- How to specify a custom compare function for a priority queue?

These aspects are most cleanly discussed separately.

Unfortunately the presented (incomplete) example code is not well suited for discussing either aspect, so I just disregard it.

### What is a lambda capture.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct S
{
    int a_;

    void foo() const
    {
        // Compiles nicely:
        [this]() -> void { printf( "%d\n", a_ ); }();

        // Doesn't compile, oh why!:
        int b = 666;
        [this]() -> void { printf( "%d\n", b ); }();
    }
};

auto main()
    -> int
{ S{ 42 }.foo(); }
```

MinGW g++ 5.1.0 provides the following diagnostics (compilation errors):

```
x1.cpp: In lambda function:
x1.cpp:14:44: error: 'b' is not captured
         [this]() -> void { printf( "%d\n", b ); }();
                                            ^
x1.cpp:14:14: note: the lambda has no capture-default
         [this]() -> void { printf( "%d\n", b ); }();
              ^
x1.cpp:13:13: note: 'int b' declared here
         int b = 666;
             ^
```

To understand the “not captured”, let's *implement the lambdas manually*, just doing a code transformation equivalent to what the compiler does with it:

```
    void foo() const
    {
        // Compiles nicely:
        //[this]() -> void { printf( "%d\n", a_ ); }();
        class Functor_a
        {
        private:
            S const* captured_this_;

        public:
            void operator()()
            { printf( "%d\n", captured_this_->a_ ); }

            Functor_a( S const* this_capture )
                : captured_this_( this_capture )
            {}
        };
        Functor_a f_a{ this };
        f_a();

        // Doesn't compile, oh why!:
        int b = 666;
        // [this]() -> void { printf( "%d\n", b ); }();
        class Functor_b
        {
        private:
            S const* captured_this_;

        public:
            void operator()()
            { printf( "%d\n", b ); }

            Functor_b( S const* this_capture )
                : captured_this_( this_capture )
            {}
        };
        Functor_b f_b{ this };
        f_b();
    }
};
```

The diagnostic is now more clear. Since `Functor_b` is a class, and since a class in C++ is completely free-standing entity, its code has no relation to or access to things in a particular invocation of `foo()`. So the compiler doesn't accept the reference to some unspecified `b`, but notes that if you really meant the `b` in the containing scope, then hey, that name `b` refers to a different variable in each call of `foo`, and isn't a valid choice:

```
x2.cpp: In member function 'void S::foo() const::Functor_b::operator()()':
x2.cpp:37:35: error: use of local variable with automatic storage from containing function
                 { printf( "%d\n", b ); }
                                   ^
x2.cpp:28:17: note: 'int b' declared here
             int b = 666;
                 ^
```

One solution is to **capture** the *value*, i.e. copy it into the functor class instance, e.g. as follows:

```
        class Functor_b
        {
        private:
            int const captured_b_;

        public:
            void operator()()
            { printf( "%d\n", captured_b_ ); }

            Functor_b( int const b_capture )
                : captured_b_( b_capture )
            {}
        };
        Functor_b f_b{ b };     // ← The capture.
        f_b();                  // ← Using the captured value.
```

Alternatively you could capture a pointer to the variable, *capture by reference*. In that the case the pointer is only valid for the lifetime of the variable. So you'd better not keep a functor instance around after that.

Expressed in lambda notation the capture of the value can look like this:

```
[b]() -> void { printf( "%d\n", b ); }();
```

Or like this, with a general capture-whatever's-needed-by-value `=`:

```
[=]() -> void { printf( "%d\n", b ); }();
```

Capturing by reference, i.e. a pointer, looks like this:

```
[&]() -> void { printf( "%d\n", b ); }();
```

### How to specify a compare function for a `std::priority_queue`.

E.g. like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct S
{
    string name;
    int birth_year;
};

auto main() -> int
{
    struct Age_sort
    {
        auto operator()( S const& a, S const& b )
            -> bool
        { return (a.birth_year < b.birth_year); }
    };
    using Q = priority_queue< S, vector<S>, Age_sort >;
    Q pq;
    pq.push( S{ "beta", 1980 } );
    pq.push( S{ "alfa", 1992 } );
    pq.push( S{ "charlie", 1971 } );
    while( not pq.empty() )
    {
        cout << pq.top().name << ' ' << pq.top().birth_year << endl;
        pq.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer, I can see what capture really does now.